# Internal queue in mule

Tags: queue, mule, polling

Any example of internal queue where I can store messages and then take 1 message poll HTTP endpoint, if the event is not successful, then again insert inside queue

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is an in-memory queue, take a look at [VM Endpoints](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/VM+Transport+Reference). The documentation describes them as:

> You can use the Java Virtual Machine (VM) transport for intra-JVM
>   communication between Mule flows. This transport by default uses
>   in-memory queues but can optionally be configured to use persistent
>   queues.

Comment: I want to store variable values (job id) inside VM and then poll Http endpoint. Can you show me an sample example

Comment: I don't have an example. I'd suggest taking a look at the documentation and attempting a solution. It's worth looking at the [HTTP Connector](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Connector) and [Poll Scope](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Poll+Reference) too. If you have issues with building a solution post your code on here and people will be willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is a transactional poll of a VM queue.  The Mule User Guide has a nice introduction to the concept [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Transaction+Management).

You would simply "BEGIN" a transaction within your `<vm:inbound-endpoint />`, and use a `<rollback-exception-strategy />` with the remainder of your flow.  You could then add a `<http:request />` to make the HTTP request.